# Safari jQuery ghosting effect on .fadeIn() / .hide()

Tags: jquery, safari

In Safari, I'm noticing a buggy ghosting effect when using `fadeIn()` and `hide()` repeatedly.

When hidden, it still shows some kind of <s>border</s> outline where the element used to be.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlmmns/7rxvf/8/

I'm using Safari version 6.0.3 (8536.28.10) on OS X 10.8.3.

**Update:** As [roasted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851738/safari-jquery-ghosting-effect-on-fadein-hide?noredirect=1#comment22558795_15851738) has suggested, setting `outline: 1px solid transparent;` on the element, did the trick.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess, but I've seen this before in webkit browsers, and if it is what I think it is, it's a browser bug ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce bug here on safari under win7 but as suggested by adeneo, i've already meet this kind of bug under webkit based browsers. In your case, i'd try using something like setting CSS property outline: .error-tip {outline:1px solid transparent;}   Try this and see if its working for you.

Comment: @roasted: Setting outline to transparent did the trick! Many, many thanks!

Comment: @adeneo: I thought it was a webkit bug, too. But in Chrome it doesn't occur.